# QGIS Processing Script Corrupts Accented Characters

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am using a processing script to refactor fields for three different input layers and save the refactored results to numerous output types (.shp, .tab, .xlsx)

The input layers have string values that contain accents (French).  However, the output layers end up corrupted.

I have looked at another post in which they talk about .cpg files and changing the default for OGR.  I have done that but the data still comes out wrong, though it is different than if I didn't add the code to implicitly get OGR to work in utf-8.

My source layers are in UTF-8.
My output layers appear to be in UTF-8.

I am pasting my code below. I use the processing.run() to execute native:saveFeatures which I copied from the history for manually running the Processing Tool "Save Vector Features To File".  When I run that tool, or the Refactor Fields tool, the output does have the correct accents in the data.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os


# Section removed to adhere to stackOverflow char limit
# This section had all the import statements

orgEncoding=QgsSettings().value('/Processing/encoding') # save setting
QgsSettings().setValue('/Processing/encoding', 'utf-8') # set uft8

# Section removed to adhere to stackOverflow char limit
# This section had all the required QGIS processing script function calls 
# This section also had the initAlgorithm

   

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    """
    Here is where the processing itself takes place.
    """
    
    global renamer
    sdcFileName = 'Eligible_Satellite_Dependent_Communities'
    etcFileName = 'Eligible_Transport_Communities'
    roadsFileName = 'Eligible_Roads'
    sdcFileName_Fr = 'Collectivités_dépendantes_des_satellites_admissibles'
    etcFileName_Fr = 'Collectivités_admissibles_sans_transport_à_grande_capacité'
    roadsFileName_Fr = 'Routes_admissibles'
    
    
    version = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.VERSION,
        context
    )

# Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
    # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
    # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
    

    #----------------------------------------
    sdcs = self.parameterAsSource(
        parameters,
        self.SDCS,
        context
    )
    
    sdccommid = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCCOMMID,
        context
    )
    
    sdcnameen = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCNAMEEN,
        context
    )
    
    sdcnamefr = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCNAMEFR,
        context
    )
    
    sdclat = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCLAT,
        context
    )
    
    sdclon = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCLON,
        context
    )
    
    sdcprovterr = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.SDCPROVTERR,
        context
    )
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    etcs = self.parameterAsSource(
        parameters,
        self.ETCS,
        context
    )
    
    etccommid = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCCOMMID,
        context
    )
    
    etcnameen = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCNAMEEN,
        context
    )
    
    etcnamefr = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCNAMEFR,
        context
    )
    
    etcprovterr = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCPROVTERR,
        context
    )
    
    etcsatdep = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCSATDEP,
        context
    )
    
    etclat = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCLAT,
        context
    )
    
    etclon = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ETCLON,
        context
    )
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 
    roads = self.parameterAsSource(
        parameters,
        self.ROADS,
        context
    ) 
    
    roadid = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ROADID,
        context
    )
    
    roadname = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ROADNAME,
        context
    )
    
    roadrank = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ROADRANK,
        context
    )
    
    roadclass = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ROADCLASS,
        context
    )
    
    roadlengthkm = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.ROADLENGTHKM,
        context
    )
    
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    inputSAVEPATH = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.INPUTSAVEPATH,
        context
    )
    
    # Check to see if format specific directories exist. If not, create
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/mapinfo")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/mapinfo")
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/esri")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/esri")
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/mapinfo")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/mapinfo")
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/esri")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/esri")
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/google")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/EN/google")
    if not (os.path.exists(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/google")):
        os.makedirs(inputSAVEPATH+"/FR/google")

    # If source was not found, throw an exception to indicate that the algorithm
    # encountered a fatal error. The exception text can be any string, but in this
    # case we use the pre-built invalidSourceError method to return a standard
    # helper text for when a source cannot be evaluated
    if sdcs is None or etcs is None or roads is None:
        raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.SDCS))
    
    
    # Field types: applicable only to refactor fields
    # 1 Boolean
    # 2 Integer
    # 4 Integer 64
    # 6 Double
    # 10 String
    # 14 Date
    # 16 DateTime

    # REFACTOR Input files with standardized field names 
    
    
    print("***RUNNING REFACTOR***")
    
    # ENGLISH SHORT 
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # # # # 
    refsdc=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':sdcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': sdccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'CommID','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': sdcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': sdclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/sdc_en_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refetc=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':etcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': etccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'CommID','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': etcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcsatdep,'length': 50,'name': 'SATDEP', 'precision':0, 'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': etclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/etc_en_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refroads=processing.run("native:refactorfields", 
        {'INPUT':roads.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': roadid,      'length': 60,'name': 'Road_ID',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadname,    'length': 60,'name': 'Road_Name', 'precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': roadrank,    'length': 5, 'name': 'Rank', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadclass,   'length': 5, 'name': 'Class',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadlengthkm,'length': 15,'name': 'Length_km','precision': 2,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/roads_en_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    # ENGLISH LONG 
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # # # # 
        
    refsdc_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':sdcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': sdccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Number','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': sdcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': sdclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/sdcs_en_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refetc_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':etcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': etccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Number','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': etcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcsatdep,'length': 50,'name': 'SATDEP', 'precision':0, 'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': etclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/etcs_en_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refroads_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", 
        {'INPUT':roads.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': roadid,      'length': 60,'name': 'Eligible_Road_ID',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadname,    'length': 60,'name': 'Road_Name', 'precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': roadrank,    'length': 5, 'name': 'Rank', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadclass,   'length': 5, 'name': 'Class',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadlengthkm,'length': 15,'name': 'Length_km','precision': 2,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/roads_en_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
        
        
    # FRENCH SHORT 
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # # # # 
    
    refsdc_fr=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':sdcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': sdccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'IDCollect','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': sdcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': sdclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/sdcs_fr_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)

    refetc_fr=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':etcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': etccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'IDCollect','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': etcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcsatdep,'length': 50,'name': 'SATDEP', 'precision':0, 'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': etclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/etcs_fr_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)

    refroads_fr=processing.run("native:refactorfields", 
        {'INPUT':roads.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': roadid,      'length': 60,'name': 'ID_Route', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadname,    'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_Route', 'precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': roadrank,    'length': 5, 'name': 'Rang', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadclass,   'length': 5, 'name': 'Classe',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadlengthkm,'length': 15,'name': 'Longueur_k','precision': 2,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/roads_fr_short_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)


    # FRENCH LONG 
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # # # # 

    refsdc_fr_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':sdcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': sdccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'Num_de_la_collectivité_admiss','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': sdcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_de_la_collectivité_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_de_la_collectivité_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': sdclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/sdcs_fr_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refetc_fr_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
        'INPUT':etcs.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': etccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'Num_de_la_collectivité_admiss','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': etcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_de_la_collectivité_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_de_la_collectivité_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcsatdep,'length': 50,'name': 'SATDEP', 'precision':0, 'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcprovterr,'length': 5,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etclat,'length': 15,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': etclon,'length': 15,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/etcs_fr_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
        
    refroads_fr_long=processing.run("native:refactorfields", 
        {'INPUT':roads.sourceName(),
        'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': roadid,      'length': 60,'name': 'ID_de_la_route_admissible',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadname,    'length': 60,'name': 'Nom_de_la_route', 'precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': roadrank,    'length': 5, 'name': 'Rang', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadclass,   'length': 5, 'name': 'Classe',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadlengthkm,'length': 15,'name': 'Longueur_km','precision': 2,'type': 6}],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/roads_fr_long_'+version+'.tab'},
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context)
    
    # Create post-processing objects for renaming layers in layers pane
    global sdcrenamer
    global etcrenamer
    global roadsrenamer
    global sdcrenamer_fr
    global etcrenamer_fr
    global roadsrenamer_fr
    
    sdcrenamer = Renamer(sdcFileName+'_'+version)
    etcrenamer = Renamer(etcFileName+'_'+version)
    roadsrenamer = Renamer(roadsFileName+'_'+version)
    sdcrenamer_fr = Renamer(sdcFileName_Fr+'_'+version)
    etcrenamer_fr = Renamer(etcFileName_Fr+'_'+version)
    roadsrenamer_fr = Renamer(roadsFileName_Fr+'_'+version)
    
    #context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refsdc['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(sdcrenamer)
    #context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refetc['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(etcrenamer)
    #context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refroads['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(roadsrenamer)
    #context layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refsdc_fr['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(sdcrenamer_fr)
    #context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refetc_fr['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(etcrenamer_fr)
    #context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(refroads_fr['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(roadsrenamer_fr)
    
    print("***RUNNING SAVE XLSX***")
    # Save refactored layers to .shp / .tab and / .xlsx formats 
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refsdc['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_Satellite_Dependent_Communities_'+version+'.xlsx',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_SDCs',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
                                            
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refetc['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_Transport_Communities_'+version+'.xlsx',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Communities',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refroads['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_Roads_'+version+'.xlsx',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Roads',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
        

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # MAPINFO FORMATS
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refsdc_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/mapinfo/Eligible_Satellite_Dependent_Communities_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_SDCs',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refetc_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/mapinfo/Eligible_Transport_Communities_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Communities',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refroads_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/mapinfo/Eligible_Roads_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Roads',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
        

    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refsdc_fr_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/mapinfo/Collectivités_dépendantes_dun_satellite_admissibles_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Collectivités_dépendantes_dun_satellite_admissibles',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refetc_fr_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/mapinfo/Collectivités_admissibles_sans_transport_à_grande_capacité_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Collectivités_admissibles_sans_transport_à_grande_capacité',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refroads_fr_long['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/mapinfo/Routes_admissibles_'+version+'.tab',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Routes_admissibles',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
        
        
        
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SHAPEFILES
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refsdc['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/esri/Eligible_Satellite_Dependent_Communties_'+version+'.gpkg',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Satellite_Dependent_Communities',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refetc['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/esri/Eligible_Transport_Communities_'+version+'.gpkg',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Transport_Communities',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refroads['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/EN/esri/Eligible_Roads_'+version+'.shp',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Roads',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
        
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refsdc_fr['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/esri/Collectivités_dépendantes_dun_satellite_admissibles_'+version+'.shp',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Collectivités_dépendantes_dun_satellite_admissibles',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refetc_fr['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/esri/Collectivités_admissibles_sans_transport_à_grande_capacité_'+version+'.shp',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Collectivités_admissibles_sans_transport_à_grande_capacité',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
    
    processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
        {'INPUT': refroads_fr['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/FR/esri/Routes_admissibles_'+version+'.shp',
        'LAYER_NAME':'Routes_admissibles',
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})

    #return {'REFSDC': refsdc['OUTPUT'], 'REFETC': refetc['OUTPUT'], 'REFROADS': refroads['OUTPUT']}
    return {}

   
class Renamer (QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
def __init__(self, layer_name):
    self.name = layer_name
    super().__init__()
    
def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
    layer.setName(self.name)
```

Comment: Test if your code works correctly by using GeoPackage as outputformat. GPKG is using UTF-8 always so it should handle your characters fine. If you will have a good output you'll know at least that your input data and code are not fundamentally wrong when it comes to character encoding.

Comment: Hi, yes, the gpkg format does preserve the accented characters. I do however need the .tab and .shp formats as the whole purpose of this script was to refactor fields and save in various formats.

Comment: But now the question is just about how to do it right. Have you tried SHP_ENCODING https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html and ENCODING https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mitab.html?

Comment: @user30184 I actually didn't think of using ogr2ogr.  I've been limited to building solutions within QGIS python framework (i.e. no local python shell) because of security limitations on our machines.  Now to look up how I can run ogr2ogr from within a QGIS processing script.  Thanks !

Comment: If I simply use gdal.VectorTranslate(dest, src) then the output is the same - the accented characters are corrutped.  Do you know how I can specify 'utf-8' to see if that might help ?

Comment: Try something like this for the output `gdaltest.shape_lyr = gdaltest.shape_ds.CreateLayer(
        "test_utf_cut", geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint, options=["ENCODING=UTF-8"]`. Everything that ogr2ogr does can be done with Python as well. There is even a Python version https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/ogr2ogr.py

Comment: THANK YOU !  We'll try that too.  A question.  I'm checking before moving into Python the function to make sure I would get the correct result.  One of the file types I need to create is MapInfo Tab.  However, when I use OGR2OGR 

ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" Test7.tab Base4Test.tab -lco ENCODING=UTF-8

I get the following warning: Warning 6: Cannot find MapInfo charset corresponding to iconv UTF-8 encoding

And of course the characters are incorrect.

Comment: I am further perplexed because QGIS uses mostly ogr functions.  If I take a layer and use the Export function in QGIS, the layer is exported correctly (accents preserved).  What is the native function QGIS is using to do the Export and conversion when I right click on a layer ?

Comment: QGIS is using GDAL and if you look at the options when you open and save a shapefile with QGIS you should see the encoding options. In opening the option is "ENCODING" and empty by default so GDAL can decide, and in saving the option is "Encoding" and the default is UTF-8.

Comment: Could you confirm that when you open some source shape into QGIS then the character encoding that is shown in Layer-Properties-Information is UTF-8?

Comment: Hey @user30184, that is very useful and IMPORTANT to know LOL.  Now why would they switch naming styles for that variable! :-(  THANK YOU